# Sharepoint 2016 and Dynamics CRM 2016 - Creating sites rather than folder in doc library

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, dynamics-crm

I'm hoping someone can help me out. We're using Dynamics CRM 2016 and Sharepoint 2016. Both the latest versions. We've done an integration between the two and realised that the integration doesn't work as we'd hoped. In CRM, we have a custom entity called 'Projects'. We would like each Project to have its' own Site in Sharepoint with its own document library to store relevant project documents. However the integration only seems to create a folder within an existing site and document library. Does anyone know a way to achieve this? Is there anything out there already?
Thanks in advance

Comment: We had the same issue... but my CRM/SP knowledge is rusted (and not 2016) I recall we created the Sites by hand and set the Link in CRM

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to this would be some custom coding or powershell.. so everytime you have a new Project entity created in CRM, you will run the script it will go & create a sharepoint site for the specified custom template you have.

Just to clarify.. powershell can call web services so you will call the CRM & Sharepoint API to perform your site creation...

Just a suggestion hope it helps.. Could you also share the integration tool u are using..